# Xamarin Forms custom frame shape around Image

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an image in my app with a frame around it to make the image a circle. I want a custom shape for the Frame, but can't figure out how to get this exact shape.

[image: Shape]

(Please ignore the house inside the drawing, it is simply there to represent an Image in Xamarin, I only need the outline to be the shape).

I also don't require the Frame to have a colored border, only the shape.

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code right now for the Frame + Image:

```
<Frame x:Name="PictureFrame" Padding="0" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" BorderColor="Transparent" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="80" HasShadow="False">
    <Image x:Name="Picture" Source="picture" Margin="0,0,0,0" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with Xamarin.Forms you can use Shapes.  The Path Data is your circle with point.

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
    >
    <Path
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        Margin="8"
        Data="M142.798828,0 C221.365114,0.164668482 285,63.9009723 285,142.5 C285,221.200577 221.200577,285 142.5,285 C63.7994232,285 0,221.200577 0,142.5 C0,139.784357 0.0759637392,137.086456 0.225882227,134.408306 L0,133.828125 L0,0 L142.798828,0 Z"
        Stroke="LightBlue"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        />
    <Image
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        Aspect="AspectFit"
        Source="brigadeiro"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="94"
        HeightRequest="94"
        />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to create a custom renderer to achieve what you're looking for. For example, on Android the Frame mask is actually implemented with a bezier path that you could control to your liking if you dive a bit deeper into the code.

Take a look at the [FreshEssentials](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/) AdvancedFrame view which almost has what you need. The modification they've made is that you can have a sharp 90 degree angle on either both corners on the left or on the right. You'd simply have to modify this code a little bit to have a rounded corner on all except the top left corner.

What you need to modify are the following:

- [AdvancedFrame](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/FreshEssentials/Controls/AdvancedFrame.cs) (In case you want the corner radiuses to be configurable separately or something else. This is the base that inherits from the original Frame control in Xamarin.Forms)
- [AdvancedFrameRendererDroid](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/Droid/Renderers/AdvancedFrameRendererDroid.cs)
- [AdvancedFrameRendereriOS](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/iOS/Renderers/AdvancedFrameRendereriOS.cs)
- [AdvancedFrameRendererUWP](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/UWP/Renderers/AdvancedFrameRendererUWP.cs) (Only if you require UWP support)

**Tips:**

On Android, the background mask for the frame is defined with the [Path](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Path/) class.

On iOS, [UIBezierPath](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIBezierPath/) class from the UIKit framework is used.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try this now!

Comment: Good luck, working with bezier paths might be a bit frustrating at first but once you get the gist of them, the sky's the limit!